# jQuery Fixed Menu trying to fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a Fixed Menu but can't figure out the jQuery to make it fadeIn when it starts and then to fadeOut when I scroll up.

The Menu up top should stay when I scroll back up with the fixed Menu fading out.

Here's a link that will best explain what I need help with

http://jsfiddle.net/Boardtalk/oh2avwoq/2/

Here's the jQuery

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('#nav-main');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 136) {
            nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the CSS

```
.fixed-nav { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
width: 95%;
border: 5px solid transparent;
border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
max-width: 1133px;
background-color: #cadceb;
margin: 0 -10px !important;
padding: 2px 5px !important;
```

}

Thanks for reading and hope you can help. I've searched for several days but can't figure out a solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/Boardtalk/oh2avwoq/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand. But have you tried this?

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

    var nav = $('#nav-main');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 136) {
            nav.addClass("fixed-nav").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixed-nav").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

In this case, all you need is a CSS transition to provide the animation. I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oh2avwoq/3/).

```
#nav-main {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I've tried this but it kills the original menu at the top when I scroll back up.

Comment: So you don't actually want a fadeOut but an animated transition back to it's original location/state?

Comment: Actually yes, that makes more sense as an explanation. Apologies for not explaining myself better in the opening question.

Comment: That's a very nice CSS effect but it sadly it plays strangely on the mobile when I added it to the site I'm working on. Thanks though

Comment: How did it behave exactly?

Comment: Here's the actual demo http://boardtalk.org/beta/index.php The menu slides down before settling in a line - if that makes sense.

Comment: It still hides the first menu when scrolling back to top.